# grunt.js and its plugins must be installed into my project?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have read the installation tutorial that tell me to install grunt.js into my web project.
But my desired folder structure is blow:

1.`C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Roaming\npm`

include  `grunt-cli,grunt,grunt-contrib-concat` etc as global tools.

2.`D:\Visual Studio 2012 Projects\MyWebProject`

include `gruntfile.js ,html, css, js,images`

No matter what I do , it does not work, always can't find module.

Comment: If you have read the installation setup and choose to do it differently, how are you surprised it's not working? Is there any reason why you wouldn't want those dependencies installed locally in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grunt-cli` is correctly installed globally, but the plugins must be installed in the project with the gruntfile. If you don't need them in production, save them as dev dependency, using

```
npm install -D grunt grunt-contrib-concat
```

(Note: your project needs a package.json for that)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution.
In any directory:
npm install -g grunt-cli
npm install -g grunt
npm install -g grunt-contrib-concat
npm install -g grunt-contrib-uglify
Change to your project directory
npm link grunt
npm link grunt-contrib-concat
npm link grunt-contrib-uglify
grunt defalt min